# how to get class value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get an updated value from an input field. So I setup a listener

```
$('.product-quantity input').change( function() {


console.log($(this).parents('.product')[0].id)
var id  = $(this).parents('.product')[0].id;
 var classgroup = $(this).parents('.product')[0]
 for (var i = 0; i < classgroup.childNodes.length; i++){

    if (classgroup.childNodes[i].className == "product-quantity") {

      console.log(classgroup.childNodes[i])
      var target = classgroup.childNodes[i]

    }
 }
 });
```

classgroup.childNodes[i] output this html

```
 <div class="product-quantity">
  <input type="number" id="productquantity" value="1" min="1">
 </div>
```

what I want to do now is get the user input in value. It is suppose to be simple but I can't figure it out 
I've tried these but no success 
     console.log(target.attr('value'))

```
      target.each(function(){
        console.log(this.value)
      })
```

how can I get the value number for the output html?

Comment: FYI, you can replace `$(this).parents('.product')[0]` with `this.parentNode.closest(".product")` in newer browsers. And you can remove the `.parentNode` if `this` doesn't have that class.

Comment: @rockstar is the later compatible with older browser?

Comment: No, you'd need a polyfill for that. Better than loading a large library though, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?  You can grab the `val` of the input itself, and log on change (or whatever you would like to do).

```js
$('#productquantity').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-quantity">
  <input type="number" id="productquantity" value="1" min="1">
</div>
```